# MoveIt! Setup links are red

Tags: gazebo, rviz, moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i created a robot model with xacro and added properties with MoveIt!.
While configuring my robot in the MoveIt! Setup some links were in a light red.
Does anyone see a problem with this rails (they are connected with the plate)
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296673/moveit!-setup-links-are-red/) by [vonunwerth](https://answers.ros.org/users/34864/vonunwerth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2018-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved by myself.
I did some weird things with the  tag in my xacro files.
In my files i defined this bright red color and called it mycolor. Then I associated it to all rails.
I hope i can help if someone get this problem.

---

Originally posted by [vonunwerth](https://answers.ros.org/users/34864/vonunwerth/) with karma: 66 on 2018-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0